# Internet traffic consistent with a malware infection (“mirai”) was observed

Tags: 14.04, network-manager, internet

I received information that my Ubuntu system is attacked by malware infection (“mirai”). How to fix the issue.

Comment: We need a lot more information than this to be able to give you a valuable answer.  Starting with how did you get the information, and what information did you get?

Comment: Internet Services Security Center send the information alert in mail. Other than that the information shared from them are related to their service providers identity.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirai_(malware)

Comment: I need A solution for the issue. I understood what is Mirai Malware from the wiki link.